# backrest angle mechanism for a Cargo Bike seat

Tags: mechanical, prototyping, product-design

I'm looking for a joint with an integrated rotating and locking mechanism, that can hold the load of a back leaning onto it. I have attached a dirty render of the concept. Hope this will make the understanding a little easier.
The placement of the joint is also marked.

I have looked at 3 different products that I maybe think would work with the product.

[First Product](https://www.rockwestcomposites.com/shop/connector-accessories/other-joints/push-button-ratchet-joints/424090)

[Second Product](https://www.adjustablelockingtech.com/products_variloc_aluminum.php)

[Third Product](https://www.regalraum.com/en/multi-folding-shelf-brackets.html)

I would love to hear if any of you had any other suggestions for the angle mechanism, [image]

Comment: hmm... I'm thinking of the mechanism that auto-locks the folding legs of an [ironing board](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/simply-essential-trade-basic-t-leg-ironing-board-in-blue/5574184?) ... with another linkage that rises up to take the load, locking with a ratchet action, ring to pull-to-unlock

Comment: Please keep your question to just about the engineering topic that you would like help with. Stating product names that you are involved with looks like spam even if that isn't your intent.

Comment: You should describe how this chair operates and the actions and direction of the locking - back rotation, horizontal sliding, vertical lifting?